# Newbie Angular Q - Modifying service output

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've been working on my first angular app all day and have a basic question.

The goal is to create a text field with two strings describing the current url route and action like the following:

You are on: {{urlRoute}} / {{urlAction}}

This information will be in the header bar for all pages of the application and needs to be updated as the user visits pages.

How can I run a string .split("/") on the output of $location.path() and return it to the view as two strings, urlRoute, urlAction in the root scope namespace? So far I have this from another stack overflow post:

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'blogControllers'
]).run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.location = $location;
    $rootScope.urlRoute = $location.path().split('/')[0];
});
```

while I can access {{location.path()}}  in the ngIncluded header template using the above, I can't access {{urlRoute}} - I feel like I'm missing something basic, can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Are you sure $location.path() doesn't start with a slash? In that case $location.path().split('/')[0] would return an empty string and you should look for $location.path().split('/')[1], instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are only trying to set this at runtime, and it's likely that route may not even get set before `run()` fires. Even if it was there you have no way to listen for changes

Listen to one of the `routeChange` events

```
.run(function($routeScope, $location){

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(current,previous){
         /* do what you want with either arguments or $location*/
         /* log "current" to console, will see lots of properties */
    })

})
```

[$route docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route)